# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent - Get only one model per user by max date

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

So I need to get the last contribution date for a user. There is a Contribution Model that belongs to a report which has a `receipt_date` that is what I need to look at to determine this.

Contribution:

```
class Contribution extends Base
{   
    // Belongs To -----
    public function report()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Remittance\Report', 'report_number_id');
    }
}
```

Report:

```
class Report extends Base
{
    // Has Many -----
    public function contributions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Remittance\Contribution', 'report_number_id');
    }
}
```

This is what I am TRYING to do:

`(new App\Models\Remittance\Contribution)->select(['vip_id', 'report_number_id'])
            ->with(['report' => function($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw('max(receipt_date)'));
            }])
            ->whereIn('vip_id', $vipIds)->groupBy('vip_id')->get();`

So the idea here is that I want one contribution that has a report attached to it with the latest receipt date. However, I get one contribution per user, but the report relationship is null for all of them.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up being able to do it this way:

```
(new App\Models\Remittance\Report)->select(DB::raw('max(receipt_date) as lastReceiptDate, cr_member_transaction.vip_id'))
            ->join('cr_member_transaction', 'cr_report_transaction.report_number_id', '=', 'cr_member_transaction.report_number_id')
            ->whereIN('cr_member_transaction.vip_id', $vipIds)
            ->groupBy('cr_member_transaction.vip_id')->get()->lists('lastReceiptDate', 'vip_id');
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try `using ->distinct()` in the query.

Comment: which part of the query specfically?

Comment: Should be able to use it , after the groupBy but before the get()